# Cassandra - Impact of configuring ColumnFamilies

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm in the process of researching into various NoSQL technologies and currently looking into Cassandra (so I'm at a beginner level with regard to this!).

My understanding is you have to define ColumnFamilies in a config file - if you want to change a column family or add a new one, you have to restart Cassandra. What I'd like to know is what is the overall impact of this, in particular with regard to "downtime"?

e.g.
- presumably every node you have Cassandra running on, needs to be reconfigured and restarted
- suppose you have 10 nodes - how does it work if 5 nodes have been updated/restarted but the other 5 haven't? Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one (of many) things that will be addressed in the upcoming release; 0.7.

Please read the wiki page about [live schema updates](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/LiveSchemaUpdates)

Comment: Great, thanks. Does that mean to apply a schema update, you do **not** need to restart Cassandra? (It doesn't say explicitly, so just want to make sure I've understood fully)

Comment: Found further info that clarified: http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/Should-I-use-Cassandra-for-general-purpose-DB-td4938505.html